# unable to login using serial console but WinSCP allowed to login the VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, winscp, gcloud-compute

root partition of rhel vm was 100% full and not able to logged using SSH not even via serial console. Using the cloud console I was able to resize the disk size from 50GB to 100GB. To resize the disk at OS layer need to login to the system as a root user to execute command like growpart and growfs.

Since I don't have the root password, startup script doesn't allow me to change the root password on the same vm. is it expected?

At the same time we able to login to the server using WinSCP using different account to delete some files from the VM to release some space as root partition is 100% full.

WinSCP and Cloud Serial Console use the same port - 22, my question is why WinSCP is allowed to login to VM having root partition 100% full and VM Serial Console is not allowed to log in?

How much memory does it required to connect a VM instance by the WinSCP or GCP Serial console?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).